# invoke method in Model from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token

I want to invoke the generate_token method in a Model from my Controller, but I get an error of: undefined method generate_token.

my controller

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
    def login_validate
      User.generate_token(:token)
      ....
    end
end
```

this is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def generate_token(token)
       begin
          self[token] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
       end  while User.exists?(token => self[token])
    end
end
```

---

the whole login_validate method in users_controller

```
def login_validate
    @user = User.find_by_email params[:email]
    if @user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    cookies.permanent[:token] = @user.token
    render :json => @user
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your code : 
"but this is a error that undefined method generate_token"
 **That's because you are calling the method with class Name(User.generate_token) but generate_token appears to be a instance method.
If you want to invoke instance method you have to create an object of that class.
But if you want to invoke, the class level method then make sure your method holds self. at the beginning.**

**If you are trying to generate a random token & return it to controller then try this:**

```
#users_controller.rb 
  unique_token = User.genereate_token
```

**Following method is a class level method(as it uses self), so call it like User.generate_token**

```
 # user.b
def self.generate_token 
  begin 
    generated_token = rand(1000..5000)
  end while User.exists?(:token => generated_token) 
  generated_token
end
```

Comment: Share the complete error log & the controllers login_validate methods body section ?

Comment: you are right, I ran your code, but it still had a error: undefine local variable or method 'token'

Comment: You must be getting this error because of "User.exists?(:token => generated_token)", I assumed your user model holds attribute(token), please share which attribute in your user model holds this token attribute, just replace with that name & your issue will be fixed.

Comment: yeah , you are so smart, I delete exists? , and it works, but I check the cookie in browser, the token don't be create, I just wanna create a token and keep a user session

Comment: assigning the token to session is a different thing, here you were trying to find any user who is associated with the generated token or Not.